# nodejs Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object String]

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm starting coding using nodejs with express.
So i did this in my file test.js which is into my folder routes :

```
const express = require('express');

const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`I'm a test`);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Then, in my server.js :

```
const test = require('./server/routes/test');
app.use('/test', test);
```

In my browser, it tells me Cannot get/test

I don't understand why. Need for help.
Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific about the error? Also I think you have back ticks instead of quotes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The problems seems to be how you are mounting the router. Looking the the [router middleware API](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) it seems you should be doing it like this.

test.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("I'm a test");
  next();
});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const test = require('./test'); 

app.use('/', test);

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `"I'm a test"` inside `res.send()`, I mean add `"` around that String.

Answer (score 0):

in order to access `/test` use `router.get('/'` and `app.use('/test'`
because express will concatenate `/` and `/test`.

in your case you have to access `/test/test` so do this and enter `/test` in your borwser:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = new express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => { res.send("I'm a test"); });

module.exports = router;
```

Then, in your server.js :

```
const test = require('./server/routes/test'); app.use('/test', test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix that should resolve your issue.

Replace

```
const router = new express.Router();
```

With

```
const router = express.Router();
```